# Conjugaison correcte de « êtes vous allé ? »

Tags: grammaire, orthographe, accord, conjugaison

J'ai vu plusieurs conjugaisons pour la phrase « êtes vous allé ? » et je me demande laquelle est correcte.

Comme le sujet est *vous*, j'aurais pensé que la conjugaison correcte était « allés », mais je l'ai aussi vu avec « allée ».

Les 3 versions seraient-elles donc toutes correctes?

Answer (score 8):

1. Premier cas : Où êtes-vous allés ?
   Je m'adresse à plusieurs personnes
2. Où êtes-vous allé ?
   Je m'adresse à un homme que je vouvoie
3. Où êtes-vous allées ?
   Je m'adresse à plusieurs femmes
4. Où êtes-vous allée ?
   Je m'adresse à une femme que je vouvoie

Au pluriel, le genre est donc neutre, seul le genre féminin est marqué.

Answer (score 1):

Quand "vous" est employé pour désigner un groupe, une seule orthographe possible :

> êtes-vous allés ...

La confusion vient de la possibilité du vouvoiement. Si le "vous" est employé par politesse mais désigne en réalité une seule personne, non seulement la marque du pluriel disparait (*êtes-vous allé*), mais on peut avoir, le cas échéant, la marque du féminin (*êtes-vous allée*). C'est le contexte qui déterminera la bonne terminaison.

---

(En revanche, et sans rapport avec le cœur de la question, attention à ne pas oublier le trait d'union entre le verbe et le pronom sujet, qui est nécessaire en cas d'inversion)